# Javascript QR Scanner on my website doesn't work on mobile browser

Tags: javascript

My website use qr code scanner and its work fine on pc browser but not in mobile browser.

Can someone help? I searched for similar issues but don't understand the answer. This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var arg = {
                resultFunction: function(result) {
                    $('#as').append($("<input hidden='text' name='code' id='road' value='" + result.code + "'><br><label>QR Code Berhasil Discan, Silahkan Klik Allow / Berbagi data lokasi</label><br>"));
                    var x = document.getElementById("ar");
                    if (navigator.geolocation) {
                        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(showPosition);
                      } else { 
                        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
                      }
                      function showPosition(position) {
                        x.innerHTML="<input hidden='text' name='lat' value='" + position.coords.latitude + 
                        "'><input hidden='text' name='long' value='" + position.coords.longitude + "'><label>Lokasi Telah didapatkan, silahkan Klik Submit</label>";
                    }
                }
            };
            $("canvas").WebCodeCamJQuery(arg).data().plugin_WebCodeCamJQuery.play();
        </script>
```

Comment: How is this a "php" question? There's only JS posted.

Comment: i use php to send the data from that qr and geolocation. i dont know it related or not but maybe i should not use the tag. Thanks

Comment: Well, if it is/was a php related issue, start by enabling error reporting to see if it throws any (errors). I can't be of help with the JS, sorry.

Comment: Its ok pals, thanks for the advice

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: on my phone. i use google chrome 76.0.----

Comment: Is it an ios phone? because WebCodeCamJQuery doesn't seem to support ios

Comment: No, Its Android